# Visual Studio 2017 WebSite Menu "Enable C# 6 / VB 14" fails to load Nuget Package

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2017, roslyn, system-codedom-compiler

Since a while whenever I click on the WebSite menu "Enable C# 6 / VB 14" I get an exception message saying that "Package  Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform 1.0.2" is not found in following primary resource(s): "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Web Tools\Packages"

I check the folder and see that it is upgraded to version 1.0.3. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Web Tools\Packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.3)

How can I bring the menu again intact in order to point to the correct version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I bring the menu again intact in order to point to the correct version?

If you want to bring the menu again, you should **uninstall the the package** "`Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`" from your website project.

[image]

Then point to the correct version.

Besides, if you want to resolve the error "*Package Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform 1.0.2" is not found ...*", you can download that package from [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform/1.0.2) with **version 1.0.2**. Then set it to the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Web Tools\Packages\`. In this case, you will never get that error when you enable "`Enable C# 6 / VB 14`".