# How can I use the latest VB.NET language level in an ASP.NET web site project?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, aspnet-compiler

I've been tasked with modernising a web application developed in 2009. It is written in VB.NET and using ASP.NET WebForms. I would  like to use the latest language constructs in VB.NET.

I get helpful pointers saying "Visual Basic 10.0 does not allow string interpolation", which was what I was trying to use, but I failed to find a way to raise the language level.

I have the tips in this related question [How to change the VB.NET language version in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122660/how-to-change-the-vb-net-language-version-in-visual-studio-2015), but they did not help in this context.

In ReSharper properties, I could set the "VB Language Level" for each of the four different projects to "Visual Basic .NET 15". This changes a line of XML in the project's  .DotSetting file, and this setting changes how ReSharper analyzes the code, but alas, this did *not* take away the compilation errors.

How do I enable support in Visual Studio 2017 for the latest version of VB.NET in an ASP.NET Web Site or Web Application project?

Comment: You need to edit Web.config to use DotNetCompilerPlatform in CodeDomProviders.

Answer (score 8):

To use the latest VB.NET or C# with ASP.NET Web Applications and Web Sites projects you need to install or update two Rosyln Nuget packages.

Microsoft:

> When you have a solution open which has at least one web project which
>   is targetting .NET 4.5+ and does not have the DotNetCompilerPlatform
>   NuGet package in the Project menu you’ll see a new option, Enable C# 6
>   / VB 14 appear.

The following screenshot is from VS2015 but the option [should be present in VS2017 too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45659533/visual-studio-2017-website-menu-enable-c-sharp-6-vb-14-fails-to-load-nuget-p):

[image]

Alternatively, bypass the above GUI feature and just go directly to the Nuget package manager and install the latest version of the following packages into the project/site to be as up-to-date with the VB.NET language as it is possible to be:

- [Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform)
- [Microsoft.Net.Compilers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/)

(NB The latest releases are [demanding](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers/) .NET 4.6+ is *installed* on the system for the compiler to run, but can compile code targeting any platform).

This will likely get you sorted for C# 6/VB 14. There is one last step to get VB 15: edit the langversion in the web.config file so that it reads `15.0` (or `latest` if you want to be on the newest version - this in my preferred option).

```
<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:15.0 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
 </compilers>
```

Unfortunately I have found myself having to edit the `langversion` after upgrading my Roslyn to C# 7.0 and then to 7.1 so it is definitely something to look out for.

By the way, this answer doesn't just apply to *old* projects - even new web projects created in VS 2017 need this fix if the template used doesn't reference the Nuget compiler packages. Roslyn is not mandatory and the template for e.g. a new Web Site has reportedly not been updated.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions was quite easy:

- Update Nuget packages for solution, install "Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform". That will also install Microsoft.Net.Compilers
- Then, upgrade the version of Microsoft.Net.Compilers to the latest stable version

Comment: You should also have NuGet install 'Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetcompilerPlatform.WebSites', which solved my issue with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

And this is the solution to get rid of the red squiggles underneath any language construct that Visual Studio 2017 thinks is unsupported.

The web.config contained this:

```
    <system.codedom>
      <compilers>
        <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
    type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
     </compilers>
   </system.codedom>
```

in which `/langversion:default` had to be replaced with `/langversion:14.0` like this:

```
    <system.codedom>
      <compilers>
        <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
    type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14.0 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
     </compilers>
   </system.codedom>
```

I found a reference to this on https://github.com/aspnet/RoslynCodeDomProvider/issues/16

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me -- see `/langversion:latest` below

```
<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:latest /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
    <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
    type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:latest /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
  </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

Comment: You had a typo in your text there, but not in the code: `/langversion:latest`   (and not "lastest").