# Upgrade to VB 15.0 in an ASP.NET web site project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-config, roslyn

I'm trying to use VB 15.0 in an ASP.NET website project, but when I try to set the language version to `15.0`, I get the following error:

```
BC2014: the value '15.0' is invalid for option 'langversion'
```

And if I set it to `latest`, I get this error:

```
BC2014: the value 'latest' is invalid for option 'langversion'
```

I'm "setting the language version" by changing the `/langversion:` section of the line

```
<compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
```

of my Web.config to `/langversion:15.0` or `/langversion:latest`.

---

So far I have tried ensuring my `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` and `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` NuGet packages are up to date as explained in [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49071549/how-can-i-use-the-latest-vb-net-language-level-in-an-asp-net-web-site-project).

I can't seem to find anything similar to this problem. What should I do?

**Edit:** `/langversion:default` results in that same error, and so does `/langversion:13`. Values `12` and below, however, do work.

Comment: @AndrewMorton That results in the same error, but I also just discovered that `/langversion:13` also results in that error.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Oh that's probably good information to have; I'm using VS2017.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Closing the web.config didn't seem to do anything, and the project is set to .NET 4.7.2 at the moment.

Comment: If you go to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn" (adjust as required), open a command prompt, and run `vbc.exe -langversion:?` does it show several versions, including the ones you want to use? E.g. I get `default, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15 (default), 15.3, 15.5 (latest), latest`.