# VB Auto Implemented Property not compiling

Tags: vb.net

After quite some frustrating research into VB auto properties. I decided to just ignore them. So I had this code.

```vb
Public Class Categoria
    Private _nome As String
    Public ReadOnly Property Nome As String
        Get
            Return _nome
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub New(nome As String)
        Me._nome = nome
    End Sub
End Class
```

But Visual Studio, being helpful, suggested to use auto-properties. I agreed, I even tried that before but he offered help in the form of a *click here and I will do it*. So I did. And he did exactly the same code I was not having any luck with before, char by char.

```vb
Public Class Categoria
    Public ReadOnly Property Nome As String

    Public Sub New(nome As String)
        Me.Nome = nome
    End Sub
End Class
```

Can someone shed some light as to why the last piece of code fails to compile with `error BC30126: 'ReadOnly' property must provide a 'Get'.`?

Aparently VS is missing the same as I am, so I don't feel so stupid anymore.

Comment: Your code looks fine and compiles both in my Visual Studio as well as [in dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lLkXaI). Is it possible that you somehow (I don't know how one would do this) use an old version of the VB.NET compiler?

Comment: Maybe [have a look at your vbproj file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32123363/87698).

Comment: @Heinzi Thanks. I'm using VS 2019, installed just a few days ago. The problem is cleary not in the code I post. It's just what I have to show. Some other auto-properties are working in different places. I just cannot figure out why this one wouldn't work.

Comment: @Heinzi Its actually a ASP project, is there something equivelant to the vbproj file? I'm not very familiar with ASP, but I'm with the .NET framework in general. Kinda fighting my way atm.

Comment: And I tell you that your code is fine, it compiles *perfectly* when I copy & paste it verbatim into my Visual Studio project. What happens if you create a brand new VB project in your Visual Studio and copy & past the code from your question into it?

Comment: Ah, that changes things. Is it by any chance an ASP.NET web site project? In that case, [you need to tweak your web.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49071549/87698).

Comment: @Heinzi Copy to a new project works fine.

Comment: @Heinzi There isn't anything related to _lang_ or _vb_ or anything related to article you post in my web.config file. Not sure what to do there, and I'm a bit scare to touch everytime it breaks something somewhere. The project is a bit old, and picking it up from the dust of another dev, doesn't help either. Do you have any more specific guidelines?

Comment: I suggest that you back up your project and then try the steps described in the first answer of my last link step by step.

Comment: @Heinzi Sure. Thank you so much. I'll hit you tomorrow with same feedback.

Comment: Regardless of whether it's the case here, I have seen Visual Studio recommend changes that won't compile once made (VS 2017 in my case).

Comment: @Craig wait until you get to the circular suggestion of a change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As point out by @Heinzi and following a previous post he supplied.

[How can I use the latest VB.NET language level in an ASP.NET web site project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49071549/87698)

Updating the `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` NuGet package fix it, in my dev machine at least.